# nagios command arguments merged into nrpe command name by local check_nrpe command or remote nrpe agent

Tags: arguments, nagios, nrpe

I am running Nagios 3.5.1 on a raspbian stretch system.

I want to measure on a remote raspbian system with nrpe 3.0.1-3+deb9u1.

I can execute the remote script without any problems. As expected I get the USAGE info:

```
root@nagios:~# /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H 192.168.4.6 -c check_rpi_temp
Usage: /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_rpi_temp [-w <warning_threshold>] [-c <critical_threshold>]
root@nagios:~#
```

But when I want to add arguments, I do not understand why the arguments are added to the command's name like !arg1!arg2:

```
root@fhem:~# /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H 192.168.4.6 -c check_rpi_temp -a 60 70
NRPE: Command 'check_rpi_temp!60!70' not defined
root@fhem:~#
```

The debug log on the remote system does not give further information:

```
Oct 25 00:23:47 cam nrpe[5807]: Connection from 192.168.4.3 port 8834
Oct 25 00:23:47 cam nrpe[5807]: Host address is in allowed_hosts
Oct 25 00:23:48 cam nrpe[5807]: Host 192.168.4.3 is asking for command 'check_rpi_temp!60!70' to be run...
Oct 25 00:23:48 cam nrpe[5807]: NRPE: Command 'check_rpi_temp!60!70' not defined
Oct 25 00:23:48 cam nrpe[5807]: Return Code: 2, Output: NRPE: Command 'check_rpi_temp!60!70' not defined
Oct 25 00:23:48 cam nrpe[5807]: Connection from 192.168.4.3 closed.
```

I enabled arguments with dont_blame_nrpe=1 in the configs.

As I do not unterstand much about nrpe and nagios, I hope someone can help me further. Maybe it is just a small problem located somewhere between my ears. All my hours of searching were nor successful until now.

Thanks in advance,
Martin

Comment: You need add your custom command inside your `nrpe.cfg` file on remote server. Common location is `/etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg`.

Comment: Hi and thanks for Your help. The custom command exists and works. See "I can execute the remote script without any problems. As expected I get the USAGE info"

Comment: My bad, sorry. Can you please add your remote command definition to your question?